# Strategy pattern question - PHP

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have a class Person and I would like using the Strategy pattern to add a storage behavior. Something like this

```
interface Storage{
 public function store();
}

class LocalStorage implements Storage(){
 public function store(){
 ..
// save in a file
 ..
 }
}

class Person{
  private $behaviourStorage;
  private $name;
  private $age;

  public function __construct(Storage $objStorage,$name,$age) {
    $this->behaviourStorage = $objStorage;
  }
  public function Store(){
  $this->behaviourStorage->store();
     }

   }

   $objPerson = new Person(new LocalStorage(),'John',32);
```

My question is, how can I use the storage behavior to save the information of the object person ? How do I pass the object to the LocalStorage so it knows what to save ?

Maybe this is not the right design pattern after all but the intent is clear : implement different storage behaviours for the person object.

Answer (score 3):

Either modify `Person::Store()` so that it calls `$this->behaviourStorage->store($this)`, and then examine the fields in the object passed to that method, or have it call `$this->behaviourStorage->store()` with the field values to store.

Comment: This is perfect : $this->behaviourStorage->store($this). Is the strategy pattern applied correctly in this situation ? Thanks

Comment: It is if the `Storage` can get at the fields that it needs to store.